# What does likelihood density f(y|theta)=5 imply?

Tags: statistical-inference, bayesian

I just dont understand what dose constant likelihood density imply, e.g. f(y|theta)=5?
In addition, when I use this likelihood density to derive posterior function, it cancels out so my posterior density is exactly as same as my prior, what does this imply?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It implies that $y$ is uniform over its domain.  Since density is 1/area, it also implies that $y$'s domain has area 1/5.